# bookdown section label not referenced after backticks

Tags: r, bookdown

I would like to use a `code` part in the name of a chapter / section, and reference that using a label.

```
# Venn diagrams: function `venn()`{#venn}
```

If not using the backticks, the reference works as expected but using the backticks prevents the label to be referenced:

```
Warning messages:
1: The label(s) venn not found 
2: The label(s) venn not found
```

Is there a way to obtain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2878) in Pandoc, and I think it is by design. You have to either remove the backticks, or insert something between `venn()` and the section ID, e.g.,

```
# Venn diagrams: the `venn()` function {#venn}
```

Comment: OK thanks, good to know. For the moment I've solved this by using `$\texttt{venn()}$` instead of \`venn()\`, with a very similar result. Already tried inserting something before the section ID, but doesn't work.

Comment: You should be fine as long as `venn()` is not the last word in the title.

Comment: Yes, confirming that. Thanks again.